# installing ultisnip with vim-snippets

Tags: vim, code-snippets, ultisnips

I tried to install ultisnip on vim with vundle , following exactly this code:

```
" Snippets are separated from the engine. Add this if you want them: 
Bundle 'honza/vim-snippets'

" Trigger configuration. Do not use <tab> if you use
https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe.
let g:UltiSnipsExpandTrigger="<c-j>"
let g:UltiSnipsJumpForwardTrigger="<c-b>"
let g:UltiSnipsJumpBackwardTrigger="<c-z>"

" If you want :UltiSnipsEdit to split your window.
let g:UltiSnipsEditSplit="vertical"
```

and then on vim `:PluginInstall`.

The installation went ok, however when i press ctrl+j no snippet is shown, no list is shown.
I don't know hot wo configure vim-snippets to comunicate with ultisnips

Answer (score 1, accepted):

c-j is a very common mapping and could be used by other plugin / or tmux, Try to change the mapping to c-e

Comment: great c-j is a very common mapping and could be used by other plugin / or tmux. please mark accepted :)

Comment: ie: you can use other mappings if you wish or disable default c-j mapping but the later could affect behavior of other plugins..

Comment: look at the screenshot, ultisnips isn't working, though is launched now

Comment: mmm that's another thing let me check.

Comment: not an ultrasnips issue please check [this](https://github.com/honza/vim-snippets/pull/435)

Comment: it do nothing now, or at least i don't see it

Comment: try nbs and thn c-e in an html file and tell me if its getting updated.

Comment: i linked .vim/bundle/vim-snippets/ultisnips to .vim/ultisnips and it works now. 
Thank you